# Mongodb - getting highest result from nested item

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to get a users top score from a variety of score.
Here's a sample mongo dataset:

```
{
    _id: "peter",
    name: "Peter Griffin",
    scores : [
        {
           event: "Peter Copter race",
           score: 100,
        },
        {
           event: "World domination",
           score: 0,
        },
        {
           event: "Listening",
           score: 10,
        }
    ]
},
{
   _id: "stewie",
   name: "Stuart Griffin",
   scores : [
       {
           event: "Peter Copter race",
           score: 0,
       },
       {
           event: "World domination",
           score: 1000,
       },
       {
           event: "Listening",
           score: 100,
       }
   ]
}
```

I want to get the top score for each user, returning s'thing like

```
[{"_id": "peter", "top_score" : 100}, {"_id": "stewie", "top_score" : 1000}]
```

Here's what I've got so far:

```
   db.famguyMongo.find({ "scores": { $exists: true } }).forEach(function(famMember) {
    var newScore = 0
    famMember.scores.forEach(function(getScore) {
        newScore = {$max: getScore.score}
    });
    print(newScore )
    newScore = 0
});
```

As you can see I'm trying to set an var to be checked each time.. I've also tried this:

```
db.famguyMongo.find({ "scores": { $exists: true } }).forEach(function(famMember) {
    var newScore = 0
    famMember.scores.forEach(function(getScore) {
        newScore = { $cond: { $gte: [getScore.score, newScore] } getScore.score, 0 }
    });
    print(newScore)
    newScore = 0
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try MongoDB's **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** to calculate the maximum score per user. In your aggregation pipeline, the first step is to deconstruct the `scores` array field from the input documents using the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operator to output a document for each element that you can then aggregate on later down the pipeline. Each output document replaces the array with an element value. The next pipeline stage will be the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operator where you can then calculate the highest score using the [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max) aggregation operator on the `scores.score` field. The final step is the [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) operation where you can reshape each document in the stream to display the required fields in the appropriate format:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind": "$scores"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "highest_score": { "$max": "$scores.score" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "name": "$_id",
            "highest_score": 1
        }
    }
]);
```

**Result**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "highest_score" : 1000,
            "name" : "stewie"
        }, 
        {
            "highest_score" : 100,
            "name" : "peter"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: I looked at aggregate last night when my brain was melting... your break down was perfect.. thanks so much (and it worked!!!)

Comment: @Beertastic No worries :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommended using [chridam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29767371/3000179), but if you wanted a JavaScript alternative;

```
var objScores = {}; //Instantiate object
db.test.find({ "scores": { $exists: true } }).forEach(function(famMember) {
    var newScore = 0;
    objScores[famMember._id] = 0; //Set default for each person as score 0
    famMember.scores.forEach(function(getScore) { //loop through persons score
        if( getScore.score > objScores[famMember._id] ) {
            objScores[famMember._id] = getScore.score; //Record the highest score
        }
    });
});
print( objScores ); //print output
```

And output would be;

```
{
    "peter" : 100,
    "stewie" : 1000
}
```